# Dropdown user input then listing and allow edit on HTML page

Tags: javascript, html

hoping to get some assistance with a project please. I have created a page for a project which allows a user to add the following fields, Artist Name, Song Title, Album Name and Genre. I can add the items to the list and have the dropdown alert on all the info if selected, however I would like to create a table which then lists the fields below the dropdown and also allow the user to change either field or delete the field.

Here is a link to the JSFiddle https://jsfiddle.net/hazelbag/f2weyz80/1/

```js
var artistList = [];

function pageLoad() {
  let htmlSelect = document.getElementById("mList");
  htmlSelect.style.visibility = "hidden";
  if (sessionStorage.getItem("hasCodeRunBefore") === null) {
    sessionStorage.setItem("artists", JSON.stringify(artistList));
    sessionStorage.setItem("hasCodeRunBefore", true);
  } else {
    artistList = JSON.parse(sessionStorage.getItem("artists"));
    let i = 0;
    artistList.forEach(function(a) {
      let optItem = document.createElement("option");
      optItem.innerHTML = a.name.art + " " + a.name.song;
      optItem.value = i;
      i = i + 1;
      htmlSelect.appendChild(optItem);
    });
    if (i > 0) {
      htmlSelect.style.visibility = "visible";
    }
  }
}

function Artist(art, song, album, genre) {
  this.name = {
    art: art,
    song: song
  };
  this.album = album;
  this.genre = genre;
}

function addMusic() {
  artistList = JSON.parse(sessionStorage.getItem("artists"));
  let newArtist = new Artist(
    document.getElementById("aName").value,
    document.getElementById("sTitle").value,
    document.getElementById("alName").value,
    document.getElementById("mGenre").value
  );
  artistList.push(newArtist);
  sessionStorage.setItem("artists", JSON.stringify(artistList));
}

function ChangeActiveUser(indexOfArtistObj) {
  artistList[indexOfArtistObj].bio = function() {
    alert(
      "The artist is " +
        this.name.art +
        " and the song name is " +
        this.name.song +
        " , the album name is " +
        this.album +
        " and is saved in the " +
        this.genre +
        " genre."
    );
  };
  artistList[indexOfArtistObj].bio();
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <!-- Required meta tags -->
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">

  <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css"
    integrity="sha384-MCw98/SFnGE8fJT3GXwEOngsV7Zt27NXFoaoApmYm81iuXoPkFOJwJ8ERdknLPMO" crossorigin="anonymous">

  <title>Task 13</title>
</head>

<body onload="pageLoad()">
  <h1 class="jumbotron jumbotron-fluid" id="mainHeading">Add and List Music Info</h1>
  <br>
  <p id="mainP">Use the form below to create a catalogue of music with the below fields: </p>

  <ul id="fieldList">
    <li>Artist</li>
    <li>Song Title</li>
    <li>Album</li>
    <li>Genre</li>
  </ul>
  <br>
  <form id="formList" onsubmit="return addUser()">
    <label for="aName">Artist Name:</label>
    <input type="text" name="aName" id="aName" required>
    <label for="sTitle">Song Title:</label>
    <input type="text" name="sTitle" id="sTitle" required>
    <label for="alName">Album Name:</label>
    <input type="text" name="alName" id="alName">
    <label for="mGenre">Genre:</label>
    <input type="text" name="mGenre" id="mGenre">
    <button onclick="addMusic()">Add</button>
  </form>
  <br>
  <select id="mList" onchange="ChangeActiveUser(this.value)">
    <option value="">--Music List--</option>
  </select>
  <br>
  <br>
  <!-- <h2 id="listedMusic">Below is your music list</h2>

  <ul id="musicList"></ul>
-->
  <!-- Optional JavaScript -->
  <script type="text/javascript" src="Task 13.js"></script>
  <!-- jQuery first, then Popper.js, then Bootstrap JS -->
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js"
    integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous">
  </script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.3/umd/popper.min.js"
    integrity="sha384-ZMP7rVo3mIykV+2+9J3UJ46jBk0WLaUAdn689aCwoqbBJiSnjAK/l8WvCWPIPm49" crossorigin="anonymous">
  </script>
  <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/js/bootstrap.min.js"
    integrity="sha384-ChfqqxuZUCnJSK3+MXmPNIyE6ZbWh2IMqE241rYiqJxyMiZ6OW/JmZQ5stwEULTy" crossorigin="anonymous">
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```

How would I go about allowing the changes?

I've searched and found solutions to create the dropdown but none that allow me to allow listing the items and editing them.

Comment: Pretty big job. I think you'll need to break this down into smaller chunks, in new questions. Also clarify if you want to just put data into a table for editing on the page or permanently save the data (a **very** different problem).

Comment: I'd like for the dropdown option to populate a list into a table and also allow the user to edit the items in the list. For now it does not have to save the data permanently, however I need to save it to the session storage.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not real answer - a snippet demo only now with fake SessionStorage IIFE (real would not work Sandboxed here) and blocked submit. You or anyone can edit it - nice would be to have a table structure in place - looks like you plan responsible(?) or give some comments or specs here.

Maybe some example data - hardcoded table content, some data in FakeStorage JSON, etc. could help ?

Also not sure what missing addUser could do.

```js
var artistList = [];

function pageLoad() {
  let htmlSelect = document.getElementById("mList");
  htmlSelect.style.visibility = "hidden";
  if (SessionStorage.getItem("hasCodeRunBefore") === null) {
    SessionStorage.setItem("artists", JSON.stringify(artistList));
    SessionStorage.setItem("hasCodeRunBefore", true);
  } else {
    var stOption = document.createElement("option"); // Fake lines start
    stOption.innerText = htmlSelect.options[0].innerText;
    htmlSelect.options.length=0;
    htmlSelect.appendChild(stOption); // Fake lines end
    
    artistList = JSON.parse(SessionStorage.getItem("artists"));
    let i = 0;
    artistList.forEach(function(a) {
      let optItem = document.createElement("option");
      optItem.innerHTML = a.name.art + " " + a.name.song;
      optItem.value = i;
      i = i + 1;
      htmlSelect.appendChild(optItem);
    });
    if (i > 0) {
      htmlSelect.style.visibility = "visible";
    }
  }
}

function Artist(art, song, album, genre) {
  this.name = {
    art: art,
    song: song
  };
  this.album = album;
  this.genre = genre;
}

function addMusic() {
  artistList = JSON.parse(SessionStorage.getItem("artists"));
  let newArtist = new Artist(
    document.getElementById("aName").value,
    document.getElementById("sTitle").value,
    document.getElementById("alName").value,
    document.getElementById("mGenre").value
  );
  artistList.push(newArtist);
  SessionStorage.setItem("artists", JSON.stringify(artistList));
}

function ChangeActiveUser(indexOfArtistObj) {
  artistList[indexOfArtistObj].bio = function() {
    alert(
      "The artist is " +
        this.name.art +
        " and the song name is " +
        this.name.song +
        " , the album name is " +
        this.album +
        " and is saved in the " +
        this.genre +
        " genre."
    );
  };
  artistList[indexOfArtistObj].bio();
}
function addUser() {
  pageLoad();
  return false;
}
var FakeSessionStorage = (function () {
  var data;

  function FakeSessionStorage() {
    data = { artists:"[]" };
  }

  FakeSessionStorage.prototype.getItem = function (i) {
    return data[i];
  }

  FakeSessionStorage.prototype.setItem = function (i, v) {
    data[i] = v;
  }

  return FakeSessionStorage;
})();
var SessionStorage = new FakeSessionStorage();
```

```html
<body onload="pageLoad()">
  <h1 class="jumbotron jumbotron-fluid" id="mainHeading">Add and List Music Info</h1>
  <br>
  <p id="mainP">Use the form below to create a catalogue of music with the below fields: </p>

  <ul id="fieldList">
    <li>Artist</li>
    <li>Song Title</li>
    <li>Album</li>
    <li>Genre</li>
  </ul>
  <br>
  <form id="formList" onsubmit="return addUser();">
    <label for="aName">Artist Name:</label>
    <input type="text" name="aName" id="aName" required>
    <label for="sTitle">Song Title:</label>
    <input type="text" name="sTitle" id="sTitle" required>
    <label for="alName">Album Name:</label>
    <input type="text" name="alName" id="alName">
    <label for="mGenre">Genre:</label>
    <input type="text" name="mGenre" id="mGenre">
    <button onclick="addMusic()">Add</button>
  </form>
  <br>
  <select id="mList" onchange="ChangeActiveUser(this.value)">
    <option value="">--Music List--</option>
  </select>
  <br>
  <br>
  <h2 id="listedMusic">Below is your music list</h2>

  <ul id="musicList">
    <li>a</li>
    <li>b</li>
  </ul>
</body>
```

Comment: Thanks Tom, I made changes to the code and found the work around to add it. Thanks for the input, very much appreciated.